# How to add line numbers to equations (amsmath)

Tags: equations, amsmath, line-numbering

I have several equations spanning multiple lines, using `\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}` to give each of them one equation number. For example:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\forall &a. \\
  &a \in A \rightarrow \\
  &\ a \in B
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

To help explanation, I would like to add **line** numbers to the equations. Surely, each of them would restart numbering from 1. For the above example, I would hope it always has line numbers from 1 to 3.

Searching on the site only finds results related to equation numbering, which is not what I'm asking for; the other type of results is about a package `lineno` which seems to number the whole document, and it has some issues with amsmath.

Is there a way to automatically number the lines?

---

Thanks @mickep for the example illustrating what I want to achieve:

[image: Equation with line numbers]

Comment: Where do you want the line numbers to appear?

Comment: Are you simply looking for the `subequations` environment?

Comment: I added one example of what I think is what you want. If it is not what you intended, please just revert my edit. Take it as a suggestion to include an image of what you want next time you ask a question. It gets so much easier for people to help (and not to waste time on guessing what you want).

Comment: Thanks @mickep! That is indeed what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vincent has already suggested in a comment, the `subequations` machinery of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package fits your use case very well. In particular, sub-equations marked `(2a)`, `(2b)`, etc can be cross-referenced readily using the standard LaTeX `\label`-`\ref` (or `\eqref`) mechanism.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for aligned, subequations, and align environments
\setlength\textwidth{8cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 a &= b+c+d \\
   &= e+f+g
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
 a &= b+c+d \label{eq:abcd}\\
   &= e+f+g
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

As pointed out in equation \eqref{eq:abcd}, \dots

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up questions.

> But can I still keep the equation number as a whole as well? For example, for the second equation, can it have both the equation number 2 and a list of sub-equation numbers for each line?

To cross-reference an entire group of subequations, add a `\label` instruction immediately after `\begin{subsequations}`. E.g., if you add `\label{eq:group2}` after `\begin{subsequations}` in the example above, you can create a cross-reference to the entire group of equations via `\eqref{eq:group2}`.

I really don't think it's necessary, or even advisable, to create an explicit `(2)` numeric label for the overall group of equations. If you are seriously concerned that your readers will be incapable of  figuring out that equations 2a, 2b, etc are collectively members of a group of equations that share the number `2`, then your readers are in seriously deep trouble in terms of basic reading comprehension -- and they will likely never read your paper to begin with...

> And can I have numbers rather than letters as the line "number" (e.g. can I have "2-1" rather than "2a" in the example)

Yes. If you want this change to apply to all `subequations` environments in the document, I suggest you add the instructions

```
\usepackage{xpatch}  % for \xpatchcmd macro
\xpatchcmd{\subequations}{\alph{equation}}{-\arabic{equation}}{}{}
```

in the preamble, *after* loading `amsmath`.

Comment: Thanks for the example and explanation. It's not unacceptable to use separate equation numbers as line numbers. But can I still keep the equation number as a whole as well? For example, for the second equation, can it have both the equation number 2 **and** a list of sub-equation numbers for each line? And can I have numbers rather than letters as the line "number" (e.g. can I have "2-1" rather than "2a" in the example)?

Comment: @renyuneyun - The answer to both of your follow-up questions is "yes". Please see the addendum I just posted for more information.